# How to insert a cell value from another cell in an appendRow app script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

forgive me, I am new to app script. Thank you in advance.

I have a submit button form with a range of data, the destination is in another sheet. However, I need to insert the date, entity name and office in the appendRow.

The form:

| DATE : | Entity Name : | Office : |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **ID** | **STOCK NO.** | **UNIT** | **DESCRIPTION** | **QUANTITY** |
| 1 | JTL-0005 | PC | BROOM, SOFT (TAMBO) | 1 |

Output (another sheet) :

| **DATE** | **ENTITY NAME** | **OFFICE** | **ID** | **STOCK NO.** | **UNIT** | **DESCRIPTION** | **QUANTITY** |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | JTL-0005 | PC | BROOM, SOFT (TAMBO) | 1 |  |  |  |

Above output only appends the row. How do I submit it with those values also.

Submit button code:

```
function btn_dataEntryPrevSubmit(){
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  var response = ui.alert('Are you sure you want to continue?', 
ui.ButtonSet.YES_NO);
  var result = ui.alert('Successfully submitted request!',ui.ButtonSet.OK)
  
  if (response == ui.Button.YES) {
    const idCell = formDE.getRange("A4")

    /*
    let deDate = formDE.getRange("F4")
    let deEntityName = formDE.getRange("F8")
    let deOffice = formDE.getRange("F10")
    */
    let dataEntryRange = formDE.getRange("D14:H")
    let values = dataEntryRange.getValues()

    for(let index = 0; index < values.length; index++){
      db_RequisitionOffice.appendRow(values[index])

      const nextIDCell = formDE.getRange("A4")
      const nextID = nextIDCell.getValue()
      values[index].unshift(nextID)

      idCell.setValue(nextID+1)
      nextIDCell.setValue(nextID+1)

      result
    }

      //====================================
      //DELETE VALUES IN DATA ENTRY FORM
      //====================================

      const dataEntryFieldRangeForDeletion = ["D14:H"]

      dataEntryFieldRangeForDeletion.forEach(f => formDE.getRange(f).clearContent())
  }
}
```

Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: I think that in your script, an error occurs at `const idCell = formDE.getRange("A4")` because `formDE` is not declared. So, I'm worried that you have miscopied your script. How about this? And also, unfortunately, I cannot understand your expected result. About your 2 tables, the top and bottom are the sample input and output situations, respectively? If my understanding is correct, you always want to copy row 3 of "The form:" to the last row of "Output (another sheet) :"?

Comment: @Tanaike, Sorry, I forgot to include the declarations here. 
I need the date, Entity Name and Office values also to be included inside the button function. ID, Stock No., Unit, Description and Quantity are in 1 row and the button appends the ranges D14:H, my problem is how can I add the Date, Entity Name and Office inside the appended rows with the button function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Alternate Approach

You may use the `map` and `unshift` functions to adjust the output of the script to the proper columns.

### Script:

You may use the following script as a basis for your own code:

```
function adjustData() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Form");
  var ssOut = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Output");
  var ssLastRow = ss.getLastRow();
  var ssLastColumn = ss.getLastColumn()

  var deDate = ss.getRange("F4").getValue();
  var deEntityName = ss.getRange("F8").getValue();
  var deOffice = ss.getRange("F10").getValue();

  //Extract Data
  var ssData = ss.getRange(14, 1, ssLastRow - 13, ssLastColumn).getValues();
  ssData.map(x => {
    x.unshift(deDate, deEntityName, deOffice); //Add date, entity name, and office to data
    ssOut.appendRow(x); //Transfer data
  });
  //delete data from form
  ss.getRange(14, 1, ssLastRow - 13, ssLastColumn).clear();
}
```

### Result

Since you have not shared a sample spreadsheet, I went ahead and created a test case based on your post.

**1. Form Sheet (Input)**

[image]

**2. Output Sheet (Output)**

[image]

**3. Cleared Form Sheet**

[image]

### Reference:

- [unshift()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_unshift.asp)
- [map()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_map.asp)
- [appendRow()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#appendRow(Object))

Comment: Feel free to ask anything about the posted answer so that I may give further explanations to the functions used in the script.

Comment: Oh, i thought the headers start at 14. My bad. Try changing the range from 16 to 14.

Comment: hi Thank you so much, I tried it and it worked.. I learned another coding from an expert. I adjusted a little for the beginning and ending column of    ssData    , again thank you.